# How to manage programmatically two Scenekit SCNviews that are displayed inside two viewcontrollers in the main.storyboard?

Tags: viewcontroller, scenekit

I have one scenekit file .scn that is displayed on a SCNView inside a ViewController in main.storyboard.
I can programmatically manage it from ViewController.h and ViewController.m files.
I just want to add another scenekit file, display it in second ViewController and manage it programmatically.

Comment: And what is your problem? Create a second `SCNView` and display a different `SCNScene`.

Comment: I solved creating a second ViewController with a SCNView inside in main.storyboard, associating it to a new class and manage it inside its ViewController.h and ViewController.m files.